# How to delete file with option character in name in Linux?

Tags: command-line-interface

I've got a file called `-T` on my linux box, and, I thought I could do

```
 rm "-T"
```

or

```
 rm "\-T"
```

or

```
 rm \-T
```

or

```
 rm *T
```

Alas, I've run out of simple tricks (or I'm misuing them).

I keep getting the error message:

```
rm: invalid option -- T
```

I'm pretty sure I could delete this file with some FTP client, but that feels like cheating. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The reason that all your variations on rm didn't work is because bash was expanding them to 'rm -T'. So you would consistently get rm called with '-T'.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A lot of *nix commands have a '--' option, which means "this is where the options end, anything from here onwards that looks like an option, isn't".

`rm -- -filename`

Not 100% sure if rm supports that, I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: Nice touch, I was curious whether this would work on other commands.

Answer (score 15):

Use the "--" option to tell rm that there are no more options coming.

```
 rm -- -T
```

You can also put a "./" in front of the file like this:

```
 rm ./-T
```

As a third option, you can often use a graphic file viewer and drag it into the trash.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Try prefixing your file with ./  I think this works.

Comment: Just for giggles I tried this and it worked as well.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to try:

```
gw:~/kana # rm -T
rm: invalid option -- 'T'
Try `rm ./-T' to remove the file `-T'.
Try `rm --help' for more information.
gw:~/kana # rm ./-T
```

Comment: Interesting, I wonder which distro did that for you. Nice touch.

Comment: opensuse 11.0, coreutils-6.11-9.1
Actually, even rm --help said how to do it. :)

Comment: Ubuntu 9.04, coreutils-6.10 gave the same message.

Answer (score 1):

Put the current directory in front of the file name, which will prevent the program from thinking you're passing it a parameter.

```
$ rm ./-T
```

-Kevin

Answer (score 1):

Well, back in the day you could use ls -il or stat to print out the inode of the file then use find with an -inode flag and use -exec to call rm on that file!

I guess the post-early 90's are still calling me...... :)